# Do I need to use any wood protector for my deck?

Tags: water, wood, deck, protection

I bought my house 5-6 months ago and I think they made a new deck but I don't think so they used any protector etc. Seems like they installed and didn't do anything else, during winter time water was sitting in the deck and color got a little bit different now.

Can I use Thompson's Water Seal?

Would be enough if I use 1 gallon?

How often should I reapply?

Here some photos

https://ibb.co/b5xDao

https://ibb.co/jEkS1T

https://ibb.co/hgS1T8

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some wood species hold up well outdoors even without a surface treatment (like cedar and redwood). I can't tell by the photos what type of wood your deck is made of. That being said, it certainly would not hurt to treat it. It would help stabilise the the color and protect the wood.

The type of coating is up to you, but my preference wood be a high quality semi-transparent stain. The amount you need depends on size and various other factors, follow the directions on the can.